# Как загрузить приложение на сервер

Tags: сервер, хостинг, vps, облако

Абсолютно незнаком с темой. Подскажите, пожалуйста , что гуглить и какую литературу читать. 
Есть приложение на C++, осуществляет масффоловинг. Напрягает что комп всегда должен быть включен. Рассматриваю вариант загрузки на сервер для постоянной работы.

Comment: vps — это (с точки зрения пользования) такой же домашний компьютер, только без монитора, мышки и клавиатуры

Comment: Тоесть я покупаю vps, устанавливаю любую операционную систему(или согласно выбранного тарифного плана) и делаю там все как на своем компе? Включил приложение, вышел и оно продолжает работать?